# NSFetchedResultsController - reversed NSIndexPath with multiply sections and pagination

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

To simplify my example, I develop `ChatViewController` where I need to display messages grouped into sections (one section for one day). I can load more messages swiping `UITableView` down. I need a pagination here. Messages are displayed from the **oldest** (top) to the **latest** (bottom of the table). The obvious is that I need to fetch messages sorted by `createdAt` property `DESCENDING`.

So this is how I setup my `NSFetcheResultsController` on `viewDidLoad()`:

```
private func setupFetchedResultsController() {

    let context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()
    let fetchedRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
    let createdAtDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)

    fetchedRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "conversation.identifier = %lld", identifier)
    fetchedRequest.sortDescriptors = [createdAtDescriptor]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchedRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "normalizedCreatedAt", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    tableView.reloadData()

    debugFRC()
}
```

Assuming... this is pretty simple example what I fetch from `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
Section 0
    0 - 0 - message A, createdAt: '21-07-2016 08:42'
    0 - 1 - message B, createdAt: '21-07-2016 08:40'

Section 1
    1 - 0 - message C, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:42'
    1 - 1 - message D, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:40'
    1 - 2 - message E, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:38'
    1 - 3 - message F, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:36'
    1 - 4 - message G, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:34'
    1 - 5 - message H, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:32'

Section 2
    2 - 0 - message I, createdAt: '19-07-2016 08:42'
    2 - 1 - message J, createdAt: '19-07-2016 08:40'
    2 - 2 - message K, createdAt: '19-07-2016 08:38'
```

But I need to display it like this in my `UITableView`:

```
Section 0
    0 - 0 - message K, createdAt: '19-07-2016 08:38'
    0 - 1 - message J, createdAt: '19-07-2016 08:40'
    0 - 2 - message I, createdAt: '19-07-2016 08:42'

Section 1
    1 - 0 - message H, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:32'
    1 - 1 - message G, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:34'
    1 - 2 - message F, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:36'
    1 - 3 - message E, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:38'
    1 - 4 - message D, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:40'
    1 - 5 - message C, createdAt: '20-07-2016 08:42'

Section 2
    0 - 0 - message B, createdAt: '21-07-2016 08:40'
    0 - 1 - message A, createdAt: '21-07-2016 08:42'
```

So, I have created three helper private functions:

```
//MARK: - Private

private func debugFRC() {

    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {

        for (index, section) in sections.enumerate() {

            print("FRC: \(index) ::: \(section.objects!.count)")

            for (index, message) in (section.objects as! [Message]).enumerate() {
                print("FRC MESSAGE: \(index) --->>> \(message.createdAt)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private func reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {

    let section = reversedSectionForSection(indexPath.section)
    let row = fetchedResultsController.sections![section].objects!.count - indexPath.row - 1

    return NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
}

private func reversedSectionForSection(section: Int) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController!.sections!.count - section - 1
}
```

And then I have implemented my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
//MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: reversedSectionForSection(sectionIndex))

    switch type {
    case .Insert:

        tableView.insertSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case .Delete:

        tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    case .Update:

        fallthrough

    case .Move:

        tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:

        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(newIndexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

    case .Delete:

        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

    case .Update:

        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }

    case .Move:

        if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {

            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(newIndexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

and `UITableViewDataSource` delegate:

```
//MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController!.sections!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections![reversedSectionForSection(section)].objects!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let message = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)) as! Message
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)) as! TableViewCell

    cell.cellTitleLabel?.text = message.content

    return cell
}
```

Output for `debugFRC()` is following:

```
FRC: 0 ::: 35
FRC MESSAGE: 0 --->>> 2016-08-23 13:02:32 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 1 --->>> 2016-08-23 12:59:25 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 2 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:49:07 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 3 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:48:21 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 4 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:32:44 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 5 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:30:19 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 6 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:30:16 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 7 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:27:48 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 8 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:23:58 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 9 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:23:32 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 10 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:23:21 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 11 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:18:51 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 12 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:18:45 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 13 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:18:36 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 14 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:16:23 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 15 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:16:09 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 16 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:15:49 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 17 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:15:38 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 18 --->>> 2016-08-23 11:15:29 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 19 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:44 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 20 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:44 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 21 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:43 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 22 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:43 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 23 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:42 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 24 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:42 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 25 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:57:40 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 26 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:56:31 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 27 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:55:49 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 28 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:55:08 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 29 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:53:45 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 30 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:48:59 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 31 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:48:40 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 32 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:47:02 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 33 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:45:06 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 34 --->>> 2016-08-23 10:45:01 +0000
FRC: 1 ::: 2
FRC MESSAGE: 0 --->>> 2016-08-16 09:16:38 +0000
FRC MESSAGE: 1 --->>> 2016-08-16 09:16:22 +0000
```

But it doesn't work. The problem is the following:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 34 from section 0 which only contains 2 rows before the update with userInfo (null)

I am pretty sure I missed something, but I do not know what. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm, if you want to display from oldest (top) to latest (bottom) you have to sort the items **ASCENDING**. Your *reverse...* stuff is actually not needed.

Comment: No, because I need to implement pagination here, oldest messages can be loaded into `UITableView` dynamically after swipe down with limit 50 per page. So if I sort them **ASCENDING** I fetch the oldest ones instead of the latest ones for first initial page.

Comment: I'm confused. That's the opposite what you've written: *...Messages are displayed from the oldest (top) to the latest (bottom of the table)...*

Comment: Yes, it is true... but I need to fetch them in the reversed way. Consider my example with messages from `A` to `K` and limit `5` per page. So If I fetch them **ASCENDING** I get `K`, `J`, `I`, `H`, `G` instead of `E`, `D`, `C`, `B`, `A`. Do you understand the problem?

Comment: No, I don't understand, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420231/creating-section-titles-in-a-table-view-controller-with-date-attribute-in-core-d/36163410#36163410)? It does the same thing you want to do.

The key is creating ** transient field** as Check mark the transient field in your data model for particular attribute (e.g. `sectionTitle`).

And calculating it as:

```
Message{
@NSManaged var body: String?
@NSManaged var seen: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var time: NSDate?
@NSManaged var uid: String?
@NSManaged var conversation: Conversation?

var sectionTitle: String? {
    //this is **transient** property
    //to set it as transient, check mark the box with same name in data model
    return time!.getTimeStrWithDayPrecision()
}
}
```

Then initialise `NSFetchedResultsController` as :

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Message")
let sortDiscriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sortDiscriptor]

let pred = NSPredicate(format: "conversation.contact.uid == %@", _conversation!.contact!.uid!)
request.predicate = pred

let mainThreadMOC = DatabaseInterface.sharedInstance.mainThreadManagedObjectContext()
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: mainThreadMOC, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionTitle", cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: checking it now:)

Comment: no need do anything extra for ordering of messages, simply implement table view data source methods. don't use `reversedIndexPathForIndexPath()` at all

Comment: This solution does not work with pagination... ;( but I liked your idea with transient property. However you don't need this property in .xcdatamodel at all. Computed property is enough to support sectionKeyPath.

Comment: Actually transient property doesnt want to work. Do not know why:(

Comment: what's the problem with `transient` property? it's easy way to show days as  table view headers.

Comment: sure, paste a link here

Comment: Please, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201608/nsfetchedresultscontroller-adds-the-same-cell-into-two-sections

Comment: Hi Bartłomiej, I'm facing the same issue right now. Did your reverse indexPath solution work eventually?

Comment: Hi Bartlomiej, I am also facing the same issue, if you have got the solution, can you please share the solution here or on gist.