# What is the difference between properties: numberOfObjects and objects!.count in NSFetchedResultsController's section?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I simply use `NSFetchedResultsController` with standard approach, but it quite a lot for me to find out why it didn't work. For some reason while adding new records and creating another section the same time, for first section

```
fetchedResultsController.sections![section].objects!.count
```

returned wrong number of objects, opposite to:

```
fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
```

Is there any difference between them?

Related question: [NSFetchedResultsController inserts the same cell into two sections only when controller is about to insert another section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39201608/2725435)